# wordpress get_terms function not working in my plugin

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins

hello again from a far far away place.

you know i`m trying to list all of terms from a custom taxonomy , when i use below code :

```
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy , 'hide_empty=0');
print_r($terms);
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
echo "<ul>";
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

}
echo "</ul>";
```

wp return a crazy error that says : INVALID TAXONOMY :

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [invalid_taxonomy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid Taxonomy
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

it is very interesting that you know , when i use above code in single.php, i have not see any error and it works fine.

somebody please help me !

Comment: it seems the value of $taxonomy is not valid, are you sure it is a correct value in the page other than single.php?

Comment: howdy binjie2680 , yeah of curse i check it by deferent ways , like :

$terms = get_terms('cars' , 'hide_empty=0');

you know the 'cras' its one of my custom taxonomies

Comment: in which page template, you get this error?

Comment: i got this error from my own plugin that  i wrote yesterday. when i call get_term to get the list of built in taxonomies , then it works fine but when i tell his to return me terms of custom taxonomy (like 'cras') he  return error.

Answer (score 3):

**Resolved**

I am trying to use:

```
get_terms( 'event_category', array('hide_empty'=>FALSE) );
```

to use my admin theme option and face same problem when using:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_features_taxonomy_event_category' );
```

But now its resolved using:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_features_taxonomy_event_category' );
```

Answer (score 2):

get_terms return invalid taxonomy error because: 
you have a custom taxonomy registered in the "init" hook
so in the wp-admin it doesn´t work -> your taxonomy is registered after you call "get_term"
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/get-terms-return-errors/13482#13482

Answer (score 1):

Oh my ... i solve this by a crazy solution temporary.look below :

```
function load_terms($taxonomy){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT 
                                t.name 
                            FROM
                                `wp-cls`.wp_terms t 
                            INNER JOIN 
                                `wp-cls`.wp_term_taxonomy tax 
                            ON 
                             `tax`.term_id = `t`.term_id
                            WHERE 
                                ( `tax`.taxonomy = \'' . $taxonomy . '\')';                     
    $result =  $wpdb->get_results($query , ARRAY_A);
    return $result;                 
}
```

As you can see i use a query, but i cant apply this plugin to my programming team.i still awaiting for a correct solution/usage for get_terms function in wordpress plugins.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing really to add but to make it clear: **`get_terms()`doesn't work in "admin_init"** action hook!

I did like [bizzr3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020474/bizzr3). Just put my code here because I was a bit confuse with bizzr3's code:

```
function load_terms($taxonomy){
  global $wpdb;
  $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT 
                  t.name 
              FROM
                wp_terms t 
              INNER JOIN 
                wp_term_taxonomy tax 
              ON 
                tax.term_id = t.term_id
              WHERE 
                  ( tax.taxonomy = \'' . $taxonomy . '\')';                     
  $result =  $wpdb->get_results($query , ARRAY_A);
  return $result;                 
}
```

then just call `load_terms()` in your "admin_init" function:

```
//get all terms from taxonomy Category
  $terms = load_terms('category');
```

and thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I been search this question for one day ,finally

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party.
To optimise bizzr3's code just a bit; You should use the $wpdb object properties for your table names, as "wp_" is just the default but it could change from site to site. Using the object property you make sure it should work for other WordPress sites as well if they have a different table prefix.

```
function load_terms( $taxonomy ){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT 
               t.name 
              FROM
               {$wpdb->terms} t 
              INNER JOIN 
               {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tax 
              ON 
               tax.term_id = t.term_id
              WHERE 
               ( tax.taxonomy = '{$taxonomy}')";                     
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query , ARRAY_A );

    return $result;                 
}
```

Also changed the single quotes to double quotes to use {$variables}